# How to iterate through very large string arrays in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm fairly new to programming in Android. I'm trying to create a basic app that will display to the user the possible "Scrabble" words they can make with a "rack" of letters that they input (based on the Python project at https://openhatch.org/wiki/Scrabble_challenge).

Each line of a "Scrabble dictionary" text file contains a separate word, which is read into an array of strings (words). **That part is working fine**.

Next, I would like to iterate through the array of words, and for each word, I would like to iterate through the characters within it, testing whether each character is contained within the user's "rack" of letters. If it is, that letter is removed from the "rack". A conditional statement then adds the current word to the **ArrayList** of valid words if passed.

However, the array of words contains about 270,000 words. I think this is where my problem is stemming from. I'm attempting to run this process in a separate thread, but the app is very slow to iterate through the array of words, and **eventually it crashes due to an out-of-memory error**.

Here is my code for the word analysis:

```
public void wordFinder(){
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            // Loop through each word in wordList
            for(int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++){
                // Number of letters that are removed from the user's rack
                removed = 0;
                // Create a temporary rack of letters that can be modified within
                // the loop
                temp_rack = input_rack;
                // Loop through each letter of the current word
                for(int j = 0; j < wordList[i].length(); j++){
                    // Save the letter at the position j of the ith word
                    c = wordList[i].charAt(j);
                    // Does the user's rack contain this letter?
                    if(temp_rack.contains(Character.toString(c))){
                        // Replace the first occurrence of the letter in the user's rack
                        temp_rack.replaceFirst(Character.toString(c), "");
                        // Increment the counter for number of removed letters
                        removed++;
                    }
                }
                // If the number of removed letters matches the length of the ith word,
                // the word can be created from the user's rack, and so it is valid.
                // Append it to the temporary valid word list.
                if(removed == wordList[i].length()){
                     temp_valid_word_list.add(wordList[i]);
                }
            }
            // The valid word list is an array representation of the ArrayList
             valid_word_list = temp_valid_word_list.toArray(new String[0]);
        }
    };
    Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
    mythread.start();
}
```

Additional information:

- `wordList` is a standard string array (with about 270,000 elements)
- `input_rack` is the user's input captured as a string from an `EditText` box
- `wordFinder` is called from an `onClick` listener

Comment: I would think using a database to store the words would probably be a better idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to store such data in an array. Try to use `SQLite`, and its build-it searching functions, it's much more appropriate way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a **trie** data structure. It gives you O(m) lookup time, where *m* is the length of the word (essentially one string comparison), and uses memory very efficiently. For your purpose, it is the most efficient data structure.